# Change mouse pointer to a laser in LibreOffice Impress

Tags: libreoffice

I have seen in Microsoft presentation software that [the mouse pointer turns into a laser pointer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-your-mouse-into-a-laser-pointer-77367b36-d25b-4ed2-8c87-358bc216a1e0) and is very impressive. How can I do this is LibreOffice Impress on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I think this feature does unfortunately not exist in LibreImpress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a cursor theme that looks like a laser pointer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347170/is-there-a-cursor-theme-that-looks-like-a-laser-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

for ages available as an option of the menu "slide show " > " ... settings"
see https://help.libreoffice.org/3.3/Impress/Slide_Show_Settings#Mouse_pointer_visible

still in 7.

Comment: I don't think this has what the OP wants - they don't just want to see the mouse pointer, they want some fancy effect with it?

Comment: you don't just see the pointer, you can use it as a pen ...
that's the next item here : https://help.libreoffice.org/3.3/Impress/Slide_Show_Settings#Mouse_pointer_as_pen

Comment: Yes I know, but I think they want it to be something other than a pen too, although I haven't seen the effect in question so I'm not entirely sure what they mean by "laser".