# Laser-like mouse pointer/cursor for (desktop-shared) presentation

Tags: gnome, mouse, presentation, desktop-sharing

I'm wondering whether there is a way to turn the mouse pointer into a laser pointer, preferrably a **thick red dot with a fading trail**, e.g. for a screen-sharing session with slides in LibreImpress or a PDF opened in some viewer. Ideally, this feature would be application-independent, a GNOME or X feature so to say. [This LibreImpress-specific option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195795/change-mouse-pointer-to-a-laser-in-libreoffice-impress) is **not quite** what I'm looking for. Also [GNOME Tweaks](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GNOME_Tweak_Tool/) does AFAIK not allow me to do this. Thanks for hints to a potential solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a cursor theme that looks like a laser pointer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347170/is-there-a-cursor-theme-that-looks-like-a-laser-pointer)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thx for the link. Unfortunately, not quite. I'm aware of pointer themes with increased-size pointer symbols. The toggle keyboard shortcut is nice, though you can also switch those themes through GNOME Tweaks before a presentation. I'm more looking for something you get on Apple Keynote or in Google Jamboard. It appears as if it needs an extra GNOME plugin.

Comment: Please check the [updated answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347170/is-there-a-cursor-theme-that-looks-like-a-laser-pointer) using googledot cursor theme. Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXcIe.png

Comment: `I'm more looking for something you get on Apple Keynote or in Google Jamboard` Libreoffice still does not have a setting to modify the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some installed cursor themes, you can move that folder to the `~/.local/share/icons` and then you should be able to change cursor in gnome tweak tool

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I moved `/usr/share/icons` to `~/.local/share/icons` and GNOME Tweaks still shows the same Cursor themes. Actually, I am aware of changing cursor themes in Tweaks, done this many times in the past. On the one hand, none of the themes comes close to what I described and, on the other hand, I doubt that GNOME Tweaks has the capability to achieve an MS Powerpoint/Apple Keynote-like pointer style. I suppose it needs a bespoke driver or GNOME app to achieve this. I'm looking for something like the latter.

Comment: It seems that one can develop a new theme such as Yaru or Numix including corresponding cursors, though not sure about how to design cursors with a fading trail. I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with GNOME theme design and I fear that I'm currently not able to invest the necessary time. Thanks for any further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install dconf-editor
dconf-editor

navigate to
org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-theme

try

redglass
OR
handhelds

Default : Yaru